# How to set custom value in SAN while generating CSR in java?

Tags: java, x509certificate, bouncycastle, csr

Need to generate CSR with SAN like this

Subject Alternative Names: DirName:/SN=1345332443jff432/UID=12347577400003/title=0011/registeredAddress=Sample E/businessCategory=Sample Business

Comment: If using BouncyCastle as tagged, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70494089/how-to-add-multi-dns-line-in-a-subjectaltname-in-java-with-bouncycastle except use one element, type directoryName and LDAP syntax (comma between not slash before) and I don't think Bouncy has all the OIDs OpenSSL does so you may need to do some explicitly

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem just last week, but with additional signing of rootCA key:

```
function genExtfile() {
    domain=$1
    cat << EOF
        authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer\n
        keyUsage=critical,digitalSignature,keyEncipherment\n
        extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth, clientAuth\n
    subjectAltName = @alt_names\n
    [alt_names]\n
        DNS.1 = $domain
        DNS.2 = $domain/foobar
    EOF
}

extFile=$(genExtfile mydomain.com)

openssl x509 -req -in mydomain.com.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial \
  -out mydomain.com.crt -days 4000 -sha512 -passin pass:rootCAPwd -extfile <(printf "$extFile")
```

Answer (score 0):

Able to add directory names using bouncy castle except title and registeredAddress.

Those two are throwing error as invalid OID's..

```
GeneralName[] subjectAltNames = new GeneralName[] {
                        new GeneralName(GeneralName.directoryName, "SN=2222232444343jff432,UID=310175397400003," +
//                                "title=1011,registeredAddress=Sample E," +
                                "businessCategory=Sample Business") };

Extension subjectAltName =
                Extension.create(Extension.subjectAlternativeName, false, new GeneralNames(subjectAltNames));
```

Any idea on how to add the invalid OIDs?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - Any options?